# Laravel - No query results for model When Using An Array Passed Via Ajax

Tags: php, arrays, ajax, laravel

I am getting the error;

> No query results for model [App\UserProfile] 0

When I use findOrFail using an array passed with AJAX in a foreach loop. If I manually create the array in PHP, the entity is found using the array values. When I do a print_r() on the array in PHP, the array is present in both the AJAX array and the manually created array.

**AJAX Code**

```
function checkChatOnlineStatus()
{
    var chatUserProfileIds = {"key-60":60,"key-52":52,"key-2":2,"key-3":3}

    $.ajax({
        url: '/check-chat-online-status',
        method: 'get',
        data: {chatUserProfileIds: chatUserProfileIds},
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {

        }
    });
}
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserProfile;

class CheckRunningParametersController extends Controller
{
    public function checkChatOnlineStatus()
    {
        $chatUserProfileIds = $_GET['chatUserProfileIds'] ? $_GET['chatUserProfileIds'] : NULL;
        //$chatUserProfileIds = array('key-60' => 60, 'key-52' => 52, 'key-2' => 2, 'key-3' => 3);

        /* Check Status For Chat Contacts */
        if ($chatUserProfileIds != NULL)
        {
            foreach ($chatUserProfileIds as $key => $value)
            {


                $userProfile = UserProfile::findOrFail((int)$value);

                $chatOnlineStatus['contacts'][$key] = $userProfile->isOnline();

            }
        }

        return $chatOnlineStatus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Silly mistake really. I moved the assignment of data to the JavaScript object used in the array to the global scope and that seems to work.

```
// Moved this to global scope in the Javascript
var chatUserProfileIds = {"key-60":60,"key-52":52,"key-2":2,"key-3":3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using findOrFail() will throw an exception if there is no UserProfile with that id.  It is possible that you are pushing id numbers back to Laravel's DB that don't exist.  If you don't want the exception and wish to self check, use first() or find() and then do an if check for isset  to see if a model was returned, or a null value if the ID doesn't match a UserProfile. IE:

```
$userProfile = UserProfile::find((int)$value);
if(isset($userProfile)
    $chatOnlineStatus['contacts'][$key] = $userProfile->isOnline();
```

If you are sure the UserProfile is present with the IDs you are passing, it may be an issue with a string being cast to an int the wrong way.  Check to see exactly what (int) is being passed via a dd().  You may also wish to use the native Laravel \Input::get('chatUserProfileIds') instead of $_GET.

Comment: I get the same result with \Input::get('chatUserProfileIds') instead of $_GET and I am certain the values are there. var_dump for chatUserProfileIds has a valid array;  array(4) {
  ["key-60"]=>
  string(2) "60"
  ["key-52"]=>
  string(2) "52"
  ["key-2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["key-3"]=>
  string(1) "3"
} . And it works when I remove the comments on the manually created array and comment out the array from AJAX call.

Comment: I think the issue is with the conversion of the string value by the cast.  I suggest you dd((int)$value) inside the loop to see what int is being passed.  Also - are you sure *all* the Ids are valid?  IE it might be tripping up on one of the loop items, which would break the prog.

Comment: I also initially thought the problem was the cast to int, so I first tried without it and it didn't work. I then checked gettype($value) and gettype((int)$value) for without and with the cast and I get string and integer respectively. I have also checked that all the Id are valid by passing them into the query to find $userProfile individually and that works. It seems the problem only comes when the array passed with AJAX is used.

Comment: OK, that's strange.  Have you tried $chatUserProfileIds = json_decode($_GET['chatUserProfileIds'])  and then running through the loop?

Comment: Yes I did. I even tried JSON.stringify on the Javascript and then json_decode on the php. What is funny though, if I have a statement prior to calling ::find, like echo anything, it goes through without the error and the error comes back after I remove the statement

Comment: That tells me the error likely isn't with your code in JS or Laravel, but sounds like a wonky syntax error somewhere else - like <?php has a space before it, or the namespace is slightly off, or even a slightly off ';' that doesn't break the prog, but just misses at the wrong place.   I would try copying the meat of your code into a clean test script and just add tiny bits at a time to see when it breaks.  Sorry, I don't think I can help much more.

Comment: Thanks @Watercayman, I appreciate the effort. Will try what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Here Your PHP code will be like this

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\UserProfile;

class CheckRunningParametersController extends Controller
{
    public function checkChatOnlineStatus()
    {
      $chatUserProfileIds = $_GET['chatUserProfileIds'];

      /* Check Status For Chat Contacts */
      if ($chatUserProfileIds != NULL)
      {
        foreach ($chatUserProfileIds as $key => $value)
        {
            $userProfile = UserProfile::where("id",(int)$value)->first();

            $chatOnlineStatus['contacts'][$key] = $userProfile->isOnline();
        }
      }
      return $chatOnlineStatus;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Try this simple code

   if( $chatUserProfileIds ){

   $userProfile = UserProfile::whereIn("id",array_values($chatUserProfileIds))->get();

   }

   - and iterate over result and populate online status etc and return result.

Answer (score 0):

@Muhammad Sadiq

I have tried;

```
if( $chatUserProfileIds != NULL ){
    $userProfiles = UserProfile::whereIn("id",array_values($chatUserProfileIds))->get();

    foreach ($userProfiles as $userProfile)
    {
        //print_r($userProfile->id);
        $chatOnlineStatus['contacts'][$userProfile->id] = $userProfile->isOnline();
    }
}
```

The code only works if I remove the comments on print_r statement or add any other statement like echo at that point